# Facebook authorization within non-facebook iframe without redirecting

Tags: facebook, authentication, iframe

I have a facebook application (not written by me, but have some control of its content) and its designed to run as a canvas iframe app, using the new(er) OAuth login stuff. I want to embed it in an external (i.e. non-facebook) iframe , which works fine when authenticated + authorized as its just a page that talks to facebook.

However, when *not* authenticated + authorized to run the app, obviously it needs to ask for permissions/login. It does this by redirecting to the relevant auth pages, which works if you do top.location.href, but I'd really like to do it within the iframe e.g. using self.location.href . This doesn't seem to be permitted by facebook as instead of redirecting you to the right page you get a facebook logo and a link to bust out of the iframe and go to the auth page, which I don't want to do.

Is it possible to handle the auth stuff within the iframe, and if so, how? Would really appreciate any info on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use JavaScript framework of facebook-connect that open a pop-up for permissions

Check this tutorial 
http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-javascript-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: I was kinda hoping to avoid such a major change (esp. as its not my code), but if that's the only way then that's the only way. Also that link's very helpful, thank you!